# Transpiling node server and socket.io with webpack

Tags: node.js, socket.io, webpack

I try to use webpack for my node server which use socket.io.

I have a simple server :

```
var server = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.on('connection', function(client) {
  console.log('new client');

  client.on('hello', function(data) {
    console.log('msg: ', data);
  });

  client.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('client disconnect');
  });
});

server.listen(3000);
```

And my webpack.config.js

```
var config = {
  target: "node",
  entry: {
    server: ["server.js"]
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(txt|json|osgjs|osgt|bin)$/,
        loader: "file?name=[path][name].[ext]"
      }
    ],
    noParse: ["ws"]
  }
  externals: ["ws"],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "[name].js"
  }
}

module.exports = config;
```

When I "compile" I have no error, just a warning :

```
> NODE_ENV=development BUILD_TARGET=server webpack --display-error-details

Hash: a692e23215bcd6caa05a
Version: webpack 1.13.2
Time: 672ms
                                       Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
              _/node_modules/mime-db/db.json   145 kB          [emitted]  
_/node_modules/socket.io-client/package.json  4.29 kB          [emitted]  
                                   server.js   572 kB       0  [emitted]  server
   [0] multi server 28 bytes {0} [built]
   [1] ./server.js 346 bytes {0} [built]
    + 88 hidden modules

WARNING in ../~/engine.io/lib/server.js
Critical dependencies:
74:43-65 the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ../~/engine.io/lib/server.js 74:43-65
```

And when I try to start my server :

```
fs.js:977
  return binding.fstat(fd);
                 ^

Error: EBADF: bad file descriptor, fstat
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.fstatSync (fs.js:977:18)
    at tryStatSync (fs.js:462:13)
    at fs.readFileSync (fs.js:510:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/alexis/Documents/server.js:109:21)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/alexis/Documents/server.js:21:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/alexis/Documents/server.js:56:34)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/alexis/Documents/server.js:21:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/alexis/Documents/server.js:48:19)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/alexis/Documents/server.js:21:30)
```

I use :

- node: 6.7.0
- webpack: 1.13.2
- socket.io: 1.5.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The warning comes from a dynamic require, such as:

```
const test = require('scripts/' + scriptName)
```

It is usually safe to ignore it. Webpack tries to deal with dynamic requires using a context module, which is basically a representation of all of the possible modules that match the dynamic require. 
You can read more about it here:
https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html

Regarding the error, if you don't need socket.io to be bundled in your output bundle, you can add it to webpack's externals config, and webpack will just ignore it, but you will need to have a node_modules folder with socket.io in your solution.

So your configuration will be:

```
var config = {
  target: "node",
  entry: {
    server: ["server.js"]
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(txt|json|osgjs|osgt|bin)$/,
        loader: "file?name=[path][name].[ext]"
      }
    ],
    noParse: ["ws"]
  }
  externals: ["ws", "socket.io"],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "[name].js"
  }
}

module.exports = config;
```

It is actually preferred not to include node_modules dependencies in your bundle for backend apps, and there is a webpack plugin just for that:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals

If you would like to use the plugin instead, your config will be (after installing webpack-node-externals):

```
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')

var config = {
  target: "node",
  entry: {
    server: ["server.js"]
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(txt|json|osgjs|osgt|bin)$/,
        loader: "file?name=[path][name].[ext]"
      }
    ],
    noParse: ["ws"]
  }
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "[name].js"
  }
}

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Came across your post and helped me zero in on the problem.  I have an add on question.  If I exclude all node modules, in a production environment     does that mean that I have to bundle my entire node_modules folder with the build?  Not sure how to optimize it.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: @sharman if you exclude all node_modules, than you will have to ship the node_modules folder along with your build. You could also create your project as a standalone package, and when the user will install your packages it will download all the needed node modules (just like when you install react for example it installs other packages). Regarding optimization, I don't know how the node_modules can be left external, and be optimized.

Comment: You saved me hours with `webpack-node-externals`, thank you so much!